# Understanding "Couldn't have got"

Tags: modal-verbs, syntactic-analysis, have-got

Here are two sentences:

> Sarah hasn't contacted me. She couldn't have got my message.

What is the correct meaning of the above?

1. Since Sarah hasn't contacted me, there's a possibility she missed my message
   (the same meaning as “She must have missed my message.”)
   OR
2. Sarah hasn't contacted me BECAUSE she couldn't have got my message for some reason

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: related: [Might have, may have, could have, must have, would have](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236453/might-have-may-have-could-have-must-have-would-have) and [“could have” vs “could”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61226/could-have-vs-could?rq=1) and [“Can have” vs. “could have”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/can-have-vs-could-have)

Comment: Could you please provide some feedback. Did my answer help? Did you find it useful? Are you still confused? Would you like an online reference?  I see you have asked six questions on the site but you rarely say anything. Not even a "thank you" to the SEVEN (with myself that makes 8) users who have all spent time writing answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Sarah hasn't contacted me. She couldn't have got my message.

Suggests that the speaker believes or assumes that Sarah didn't receive the message, because if Sarah had received that message, she would have replied to the speaker.

The speaker is speculating as to why Sarah didn't reply. If the speaker wanted to express **uncertainty** then she/he would say:

1. She might not have got my message.
2. She may not have got my message.
3. Perhaps/maybe she didn't get my message.

The modal verb *could* in its positive form expresses *uncertainty*

4. She **could** have got my message
   (*there's a possibility Sarah received the message, the degree of uncertainty can be inferred by the speaker's intonation*)

When *could* is used in its negative form it expresses a *negative deduction* or something that didn't happen in the past (*couldn't + the perfect infinitive*).

5. She **couldn't** have got my message.

Here the speaker expresses the conviction that Sarah did not receive the message. The same meaning is conveyed with **can't have** + **past participle** as in

“she can't have got …”; “she can't have seen …”; “she can't have read …” etc.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer seems far sufficient for this question. I just would like to note that I believe it should read "couldn't have *gotten*" as the past participle of get is gotten. This is especially indicated by the fact the statement implies a perfective acquisition rather than present possession(in which it would be correct to say "I got" meaning *I have in my ownership*).

(The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language)

Comment: *gotten* is a word only in North America; in other parts of the world, the past participle of *get* is *got*.

Comment: This would be very true in American English, and I should have remembered this myself, I try to include both dialects whenever I do. [Gotten](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotten)

Comment: @PeterShor It's also used in some parts of the English North and Scotland, and it was the historical past participle.